# Replacing New Lines in fields but not by line

Tags: excel, notepad++

I received an Excel file with new line characters in the cells and need to import it into another program which will misinterpret those newlines. So I did a find and replace with ctrl H and then ctrl J for new line character and it replaced some of those newline characters.

But then when I look at the file in notepad++ there still seem to be newlines within fields, which the Excel ctrl H is not picking up.

Applying show all symbols in Notepad++ all new lines I actually want have CR LF at the end, while all the ones I don't want have just CR at the end.

So is there a way of removing all lines with CR at the end but not CRLF?

Comment: Replace all CRLF with LFLF then replace all CR with nothing then replace all LFLF with CRLF.

Comment: How do you specify CR and LF separately? the only one I know is \n which I think is CR

Comment: `vbCRLF`, `vbCR` and `vbLF` or `Chr(13)&Chr(10)`, `Chr(13)` and `Chr(10)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I fixed it by just replacing CR with Blank

Answer (score 0):

I just did I find and replace replacing \r (carriage return) with blank. The LF's remained to separate actual newlines.

Thanks